# Reading random lines from a text file into a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am creating a quiz and need my `JLabel` to read a random line from a text file and use this as the question to ask the user. The `JLabel` I want the question to appear on are in a separate `JDialog` class from my main class.

I have been told the best way to do this, is to create a text file which contains all of the data/strings which the program will then pull information from and implement it into my `JLabel`.

I have read around and from what I am aware I need to use a buffered reader and also a file reader, however, I am not entirely sure how to implement this into my code and also how to make it so that it is a random question each time.

Could somebody please help me, my code for the `JLabel` is as follows

```
package ZillionaireGUI;

import java.awt.Frame;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class questionDialog extends JDialog {
private JLabel Question;
private JRadioButton answerThree;
private JRadioButton answerFour;
private JRadioButton answerTwo;
private JRadioButton answerOne;
public questionDialog(Frame parent) {
    super(parent);
}


public questionDialog(JFrame frame) {
    super(frame);
    initGUI();
}

private void initGUI() {
    try {

        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        Question = new JLabel();
        getContentPane().add(Question);
        Question.setText("jLabel1");
        Question.setBounds(39, 127, 383, 29);

        answerOne = new JRadioButton();
        getContentPane().add(answerOne);
        answerOne.setText("jRadioButton1");
        answerOne.setBounds(26, 183, 93, 20);

        answerTwo = new JRadioButton();
        getContentPane().add(answerTwo);
        answerTwo.setText("jRadioButton1");
        answerTwo.setBounds(130, 183, 93, 20);

        answerThree = new JRadioButton();
        getContentPane().add(answerThree);
        answerThree.setText("jRadioButton1");
        answerThree.setBounds(247, 183, 93, 20);

        answerFour = new JRadioButton();
        getContentPane().add(answerFour);
        answerFour.setText("jRadioButton1");
        answerFour.setBounds(360, 183, 93, 20);

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(answerOne);
        group.add(answerTwo);
        group.add(answerThree);
        group.add(answerFour);


        this.setSize(490, 393);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not read in all the questions when the application starts, store them in some collection, and then just grab a random one when you need it? Much easier than trying to read the file each time.

Comment: Hmm. I was not aware of this method. Perhaps you could elaborate - if like you say it is easier I am all ears and would be willing to implement code which performs as such!

Comment: When the application starts, read the file. Store each question in a collection of some sort, maybe some `List` implementation. When you need a question, generate a random number that's less than the number of questions you have and take that element from the `List`.

Comment: I do already have the questions ordered in an arraylist, however, I was told it would be better to read the questions from a seperate file? Would reading them from an arraylist be fine?

Comment: Fair enough. I guess the question is, how would I go about generating this random number and secondly, how would I then take that element and implement it into my JLabel?

Comment: I think if you google for each of those questions separately you will find all the help you need.